# Matrix-vector multiplication/cross product problem

Tags: matrices, algebra-precalculus, vectors, cross-product

How can I generally solve equations of the form $\mathbf{A} \mathbf{w} =
\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}
\times \mathbf{w}$ for the matrix $\mathbf{A},$ where $\mathbf{w}$ can be any vector? I recognize that you could just set $\mathbf{w}$ to a vector with simple values, such as $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$, but doing so still isn't helpful. Also, $x,$ $y,$ and $z$ are entirely independent variables.

Comment: Note that $\pmatrix{x\\y\\z}\times w=\pmatrix{0&-z&y\\z&0&-x\\-y&x&0}w$.

Comment: The solution set of $r\times w$ is closed under $r\mapsto r+\lambda w$.

Comment: "*I recognize that you could just set $w$ to a vector with simple values, but doing so still isn't helpful*"... Yes, it *is* helpful so long as you are smart about it.  Do it very specifically for $w = \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$ and then do it specifically for $w = \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ and finally do it for $w = \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}$.  Recognize what these three results have to do with your matrix $A$.

Answer (score 2):

OK, let's put it other way as $\mathbf{w}\times \mathbf{v}=-\mathbf{A}\mathbf{w}$.
We can write the the cross product as vector-matrix multiplication:
$$\mathbf{w}\times\mathbf{v} =[\mathbf{w}]_\times \mathbf{v}=\begin{bmatrix}\,0&\!-w_{3}&\,\,w_{2}\\\,\,w_{3}&0&\!-w_{1}\\-w_{2}&\,\,w_{1}&\,0\end{bmatrix}\mathbf{v}.$$
So you can write your equation as a system of linear equations
$$[\mathbf{w}]_\times \mathbf{v}=-\mathbf{A}\mathbf{w}.$$
Matrix $[\mathbf{w}]_\times$ has rank $2$ and its nullspace is spanned by $[w_1,\,w_2,\,w_3]^\top$.

Now depending on whether you assume $w_2\neq 0$ or $w_3\neq 0$, you can transform this system and find a particular solution. However, this solution can be found only if $\langle\mathbf{w},\mathbf{Aw}\rangle=0$. In particular, this implies that $\mathbf{A}^\top=-\mathbf{A}$.

Comment: Thank you, corrected.

Comment: What is the notation [w]x? You converted the vector w to some matrix. What matrix is that?